# Kivy: How do I nest a FloatLayout to cover only part of the window?

Tags: python, kivy

In my Kivy window, I have two sections of screen. On the left is a ScrollView with buttons, and the right side is empty space. When I click a button from the ScrollView, it is supposed to create a draggable label that can only be dragged in the right side of the screen. However, when I try to add the label to the empty part of the screen, it instead appears under the scrollbar in the bottom right.

My window is a FloatLayout, with the ScrollView and another FloatLayout to represent the empty space. I've tried giving size hints and position hints to describe the empty area, such that the nested FloatLayout only covers the empty space. When adding a draggable label to this layout, it seems to ignore it altogether, although my `test_up` function recognizes the labels as children.

Why is my nested FloatLayout still covering the whole screen? If the FloatLayout is correct, then why is the draggable label appearing outside of it?

Here is my code:

```py
class DragLabel(DragBehavior, Label):
    pass

class MyBox(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyBox, self).__init__()

    def add_draggable(self, words):
        lab = DragLabel(text = words)
        self.play_area.add_widget(lab)

class KR(App):
    
    def build(self):
        self.game = MyBox()
        return self.game
    
    def test_up(self):
        for _ in self.game.play_area.children:
            print("There's a thing!")
        print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = KR()
    app.run()
```

and my KV file:

```
#:import win kivy.core.window

<DragLabel>:
    size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    drag_timeout: 10000000
    drag_distance: 0

    on_touch_up: app.test_up()

<MyBox>:

    scroll: scroll
    screen: screen
    play_area: play_area

    FloatLayout:

        id: screen

        ScrollView:
            id: scroll
            size_hint: 0.2, None
            size: win.Window.width, win.Window.height

            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                spacing: 10
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height

                Button:
                    text: "This is a button"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: win.Window.height/10
                    on_press: root.add_draggable(self.text)
                # More buttons go here

        FloatLayout:  # <---- This still covers the whole screen for some reason?
            id: play_area
            size_hint: 0.8, 1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "top":1}
```

I know something isn't working because I attempted to add a DragLabel to the ScrollView; and when I dragged out of the ScrollView, it disappeared. I want the label to do the same when it's dragged out of the empty space, but I can't seem to get it in there to begin with.

Any help is greatly appreciated!